# Extracting some columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I have a following sample data frame:

```
x<-c(1:4)
y<-c(9:12)
z<-c("a","b","c","d")
data<-data.frame(x,y,z) # as data: 

      x  y z
    1 1  9 a
    2 2 10 b
    3 3 11 c
    4 4 12 d
```

I want to extract the column 2 or 3 using the function (note: I am using column names to extract). My code is as follows:

```
data_frame<-function(col){
cols<-c("y","z")
# column x is already there; it is not in a vector of col.
if (col %in% cols){
kk<-data[,c("x","col")] 
return (kk)}
}
```

Now, I want the output for `data_frame("y")`. However, R gives me the following error:

```
data_frame("y")
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , c("x", "col")) : 
  undefined columns selected.
```

I was wondering why R is not taking my argument `col` which is `y` here. I am a bit upset  why R is interpreting argument `col` as the name of the column. Your valuable suggestion in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part: `kk<-data[,c("x","col")]` should be `kk<-data[,c("x",col)]`

Comment: Glad it worked. Would you mind checking this off as the best answer? thanks.

Comment: Sure ! Could you please let me know how can I that?.

Comment: The check mark is right underneath the "2" on the left of my answer.